# SQL : I search the good query with select max() and select count()

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, max

I have a table named **arrived** (this table is simple, and it just saves the users that arrive at school at such day and at such hour) with the following data :

```
id  name    day         hour
1   Alice   Monday      11
2   Alice   Monday      13
3   Alice   Tuesday     11
4   Céline  Wednesday   14
5   Céline  Wednesday   13
6   Céline  Thursday    14
7   Maud    Friday      15
8   Maud    Saturday    15
9   Maud    Saturday    16
```

Now, I search the good query that find for each user : the most frequent day and the most frequent hour, that is say, the result of the query must return this lines :

```
Alice   Monday      11
Céline  Wednesday   14
Maud    Saturday    15
```

=> because :

- Alice frequently arrives at Monday, and frequently at 11h
- Céline frequently arrives at Wednesday, and frequently at 14h
- Maud frequently arrives at Saturday, and frequently at 15h

My query is below, but it doesn't give me the good result :

```
SELECT NAME,
       day,
       Max(count_hour)
FROM   (SELECT NAME,
               day,
               Count(hour) AS count_hour
        FROM   arrived
        GROUP  BY NAME,
                  day) AS alias_table
GROUP  BY NAME
```

Thank you, cordially.

Comment: If you can, instead of `day` and `hour`, just store `datetime`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure is this the right way to do it but should work!

```
SELECT *
FROM   arrived A
WHERE  hour = (SELECT hour
               FROM   arrived B
               WHERE  a.NAME = b.NAME
               GROUP  BY b.hour,
                         b.NAME
               ORDER  BY Count(b.hour) DESC Limit 1)
       AND day = (SELECT day
                  FROM   arrived B
                  WHERE  a.NAME = b.NAME
                  GROUP  BY b.day,
                            b.NAME
                  ORDER  BY Count(b.day) DESC Limit 1)
```

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92b56/4)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I just have one table named "arrived". Why do you use two tables ?

Comment: @totoaussi - Even i have used only one table named **Yourtable**. Now edited the name to **arrived**

Comment: Thank you very much, it works ! effectively, you use A and B as alias tables. Thank you very much !!!

Comment: This query will fail to return a row if the combination (max(day),max(hour)) does not exist, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/489a2c/1/0

Comment: This is a modified version returning the correct result: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/489a2c/3/0

Answer (score 0):

Try the `greatest(day, hour)` when selecting columns. You can also try `greatest(max(day), max(hour))`

Cheers!

Comment: Even if greatest is not appropriate, thank you for your reply.